# How to get Selenium user-extensions work when running Xebium tests?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, fitnesse, ui-testing

Selenium allows users to extend actions, assertions, locator strategies ([Selenium user-extensions](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/08_user_extensions.jsp)). 
With some googling I found that you should start selenium server with the proper option for enabling user-extensions:

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -userExtensions user-extensions.js
```

where user-extension.js is the file you have written containing the extensions. But how should I tell Xebium to run selenium server with this option?